Basemap with one selector
I would like the base maps to have a single selector instead of the classic check that turns it on and off, is it possible as in this figure?


In the latest versions of qgis2web the xyz layers are not represented with the single check, but with the on/off check.
In any case I didn't understand your question, what do you want to do? Please edit your question and explain better

My apologies for misleading syntax. I want to know how is the option possible that the basemaps are only selected one at a time, as shown in the picture

After exporting, edit the layers.js file contained in layers folder.
Find your layers and define the property 'type': 'base' in the variable new ol.layer.Tile({
Here is an example:


Thank you for the answer. It seems like the ['type': 'base',] line has "//" in front of it by default export, which makes the map read it as non-base layer instead of base layer. The radio function is also a default function innate on export, it just didn't read the basemaps as base-type.

I've deactivated type:base by default because if only 1 base map is exported it cannot be turned off since it is not possible to remove the check.
Using the system without type:base arrives at the same result of seeing only 1 at the same time, the one above, but allows to turned off in case of only 1 base map.
Please consider making a virtual coffee donation on the qgis2web github home to support its development. Thank you.
